# Complex key implementation on nullable fields using unique indexes

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

Currently I have a table as follows:

```
ID    Name    Category    Group
 1     Abc       D1111    55501
 2     Abd       D1234    55502
 3     Abc       D1112    55545
 4     Abc       D1113    55545    // Group can repeat for distinct Name, Category
 5     Cdb       B3345     NULL
 6     Cdb       B3399     NULL
 7     RRR        NULL    12345
 8     RRR        NULL    23456
```

`ID` is my primary key. `Name` should never be null, however either of `Category` or `Group` (but never both) could be null. Additionally, (`Name`, `Category`) should always be unique and (`Name`, `Group`) should be unique where `Category` is null.

I'm wondering if implementing this with unique indexes is the best way to go or if I should somehow split this into more than one table. If I were to use indexes it might look like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index1 ON FakeTable (Name, Category) 
WHERE Category IS NOT NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index2 ON FakeTable  (Name, Group) 
WHERE (Category IS NULL) AND (Group IS NOT NULL);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index3 ON FakeTable  (Name, Category, Group) 
WHERE (Category IS NOT NULL) AND (Group IS NOT NULL);
```

Mainly this table is to provide a list of category/group combinations for each Name. So in that case I might query `SELECT Category, Group FROM FakeTable WHERE Name = 'Abc'`.

Also, I have other tables that reference this one via ID (although ID is a surrogate key, so in actuality it is Name/Group that usually serve as the reference fields).

I'm hoping someone can tell me if this is a bad strategy and why.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the queries you will be doing on this table? For example, are you making a "SELECT ... FROM table WHERE Name='value' and (Category='value' or Group='value')" How do you query it? This has an impact on the indexes you should be creating if you want SQL to use the index you will be creating.

Comment: Sure. Mainly this table is to provide a list of category/group combinations for each `Name`. So in that case I might query `SELECT Category, Group FROM FakeTable WHERE Name = 'Abc'`.

Comment: Also, I have other tables that reference this one via ID (although `ID` is a surrogate key, so in actuality it is `Name`/`Group` that usually serve as the reference fields.)

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. I suppose I should implement a check constraint to ensure that one of Category/Group is not null?

Comment: Do **NOT** call your variables (table and/or column names) using [SQL Keywords](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words). It makes code buggy and difficult to read, is a real pain if you want to port your application and it just makes **NO** sense whatsoever! Use `group_` or `groupe` (French) or `gruppe` (German) or your language of choice - in short, **anything** but `group`! Look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5ff3b1baaba74be7ad24b473e2ca875e).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was only using these column names for this dummy example. Although maybe that makes it an even more egregious mistake.